# $_FILES array is not working properly

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to create an application in which I have to create undefined numbers of file type control.

And I have created this thing but I am unable to find the temporary path of that file.

`$_FILES[][]` is also not working properly.

Please help me by providing relevant information.

Comment: There is nothing at all for us to go on here. You haven't shown us nor even _described_ what's "not working properly".

Comment: Show us the thing you have created, and a `var_dump($_FILES)`.

Comment: <script>
       function addMoreFiles(){
     for(i=0;i<=3;i++){
  
            $("#append1").append('<input type="file" name="tt[]" />')
     }
       }

 </script>

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  The $_FILES array is for uploaded files, not files you create.

Comment: @user846224: Then the files will be on `$_FILES['tt']`.

Comment: Actually I want to tmp_name of uploaded files

Comment: @user846224: `$_FILES['tt'][0]['tmp_name']`, `$_FILES['tt'][1]['tmp_name']`, `$_FILES['tt'][2]['tmp_name']`...

Answer (score 2):

whats the encoding type of your form? make sure its multi-part from data...

Answer (score 2):

The $_FILES array always works properly. It's your code that's broken. Some things to check:

1. file uploads are enabled in PHP (`file_uploads` .ini directive).
2. Your HTML form is missing an `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: hi sir actually I am not understand this                                                                   file uploads are enabled in PHP (file_uploads .ini directive).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php  look for 'File Uploads'